# Binding ItemsControl Button to Command - Command Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, itemscontrol

I'm having problems binding command for a button from an ItemsControl. For some reason the command is not being fired. My button is displayed via an observable collection binded to an ItemsControl.

I followed some of the instructions here in SO such as binding to a relativesource and to an element name but still not working.

Model:

```
namespace InteractiveExam.Model
{
    class Resource
    {
        long _resourceID;

        public long ResourceID
        {
            get { return _resourceID; }
            set { _resourceID = value; }
        }


        string _resourceTitle;

        public string ResourceTitle
        {
            get { return _resourceTitle; }
            set { _resourceTitle = value; }
        }


        string _filename;

        public string Filename
        {
            get { return _filename; }
            set { _filename = value; }
        }


        string _resourceModuleID;

        public string ResourceModuleID
        {
            get { return _resourceModuleID; }
            set { _resourceModuleID = value; }
        }


        string _resourceType;

        public string ResourceType
        {
            get { return _resourceType; }
            set { _resourceType = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

ViewModel 1:

```
class ResourceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Resource resource;

    public Resource Resource
    {
        get
        {
            return resource;
        }
        set
        {
            resource = value;
        }
    }

    public long ResourceID
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.ResourceID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Resource.ResourceID != value)
            {
                Resource.ResourceID = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResourceID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ResourceTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.ResourceTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Resource.ResourceTitle != value)
            {
                Resource.ResourceTitle = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResourceTitle");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Filename
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.Filename;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Resource.Filename != value)
            {
                Resource.Filename = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Filename");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ResourceModuleID
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.ResourceModuleID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Resource.ResourceModuleID != value)
            {
                Resource.ResourceModuleID = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResourceModuleID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ResourceType
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.ResourceType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Resource.ResourceType != value)
            {
                Resource.ResourceType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResourceType");
            }
        }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

ViewModel 2 (this is my view Datacontext):

```
class MultiMediaViewerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string connectionStringLocal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDB"].ConnectionString;

    public MultiMediaViewerViewModel()
    {
        LoadModules();
        LoadResources();
    }

    #region Module

    private Module module = new Module();
    static ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel> _modules = new ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel>();

    public static ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel> Modules
    {
        get
        {
            return _modules;
        }
        set
        {
            _modules = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadModules()
    {
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringLocal);
        thisConnection.Open();

        string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM module ORDER BY moduleName";

        SqlCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = Get_Data;

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("module");
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            module.ModuleID = row["moduleID"].ToString();
            module.ModuleName = row["moduleName"].ToString();
            module.ModulePrerequisiteID = row["prerequisiteID"].ToString();
            module.ModuleCourseID = row["courseID"].ToString();

            _modules.Add(new ModuleViewModel {Module = new Module{ ModuleID = module.ModuleID, ModuleName = module.ModuleName, ModulePrerequisiteID = module.ModulePrerequisiteID, ModuleCourseID = module.ModuleCourseID } });
        }

        //close and dispose
        thisConnection.Close();
        thisConnection.Dispose();

        cmd.Dispose();
        dt.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Resources

    private Resource resource = new Resource();
    static ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> _resources = new ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel>();

    public static ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources
    {
        get
        {
            return _resources;
        }
        set
        {
            _resources = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadResources()
    {
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringLocal);
        thisConnection.Open();

        string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM resource ORDER BY resourceTitle";

        SqlCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = Get_Data;

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("resource");
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            resource.ResourceID = Convert.ToInt64(row["id"]);
            resource.ResourceTitle = row["resourceTitle"].ToString();
            resource.Filename = row["filename"].ToString();
            resource.ResourceModuleID = row["resourceModuleID"].ToString();
            resource.ResourceType = row["resourceType"].ToString();

            _resources.Add(new ResourceViewModel { Resource = new Resource { ResourceID = resource.ResourceID, ResourceTitle = resource.ResourceTitle, Filename = resource.Filename, ResourceModuleID = resource.ResourceModuleID, ResourceType = resource.ResourceType } });
        }

        //close and dispose
        thisConnection.Close();
        thisConnection.Dispose();

        cmd.Dispose();
        dt.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region MediaPlayer

    string resourceFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceFolder"].ToString();

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    static ObservableCollection<MediaPlayerViewModel> _mediaPlayers = new ObservableCollection<MediaPlayerViewModel>();

    public static ObservableCollection<MediaPlayerViewModel> MediaPlayers
    {
        get
        {
            return _mediaPlayers;
        }
        set
        {
            _mediaPlayers = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadMediaElementDefaults()
    {
        //mediaPlayer.TimelineSlider.Maximum = mediaPlayer.MediaElementPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        string mediaFullpath = resourceFolder + "Dubai2021.mp4";
        mediaPlayer.MediaUri = new Uri(mediaFullpath, UriKind.Absolute);

        //_mediaPlayers.Add(new MediaPlayerViewModel { MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer { MediaUri = mediaPlayer.MediaUri } });
    }

    Uri _mediaUri;

    public Uri MediaUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _mediaUri;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_mediaUri != value)
            {
                _mediaUri = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MediaUri");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand PlayCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(PlayCommandExecute, CanPlayCommandExecute); } }

    void PlayCommandExecute()
    {
        string mediaFullpath = resourceFolder + "Dubai2021.mp4";
        MediaUri = new Uri(mediaFullpath, UriKind.Absolute);

        if (this.PlayRequested != null)
        {
            this.PlayRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    bool CanPlayCommandExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler PlayRequested;

}
```

View:

```html
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Width="250" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True" 
                  PanningMode="VerticalOnly" 
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=mainGrid,Path=ActualHeight}" 
                  ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="ScrollViewer_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback" 
                  Padding="0,0,0,130">
       <DockPanel>
         <StackPanel>
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}">
             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Button Template="{StaticResource ctButton}" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                           Tag="{Binding ResourceID}" 
                           Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.PlayCommand}">
                       <TextBlock 
                           Text="{Binding ResourceTitle}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Width="170"
                            Height="70" 
                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                       </Button>
                     </DataTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               </ItemsControl>
             </StackPanel>
         </DockPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: The binding for your command looks wrong to me. Do you have any binding errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors from the output window. If you think it's wrong can you tell me how you think it's supposed to be and i'll try please.

Comment: you Could try `Command="{Binding ElementName=xxx, Path= DataContext.PlayCommand}"` and set the `Name` of your Usercontrol to `xxx`.

Comment: Where do you define your DataContext? That means, how do you attach your view model to the view? The binding in your example code should work, if you set the DataContext of your window.

Comment: Can you trim down the code to reduce the irrelevant properties and such?

Comment: @user3596113 I tried your suggestion but it did not worked any more ideas please?

Comment: @dymanoid the datacontext is set in the code behind of MainWindow.xaml at MainWindow.xaml.cs 

MultiMediaViewerViewModel mmvvm = new MultiMediaViewerViewModel();

DataContext = mmvvm;

Comment: @NathanTuggy this is already a trimmed down code. i did it that way so that those guys that would offer help can see that the main viewmodel is deriving from another viewmodel. i also included the model just in case. As for the view, i only included the relevant area where the binding will be applied. Unless i'm not getting where you are at? What kind of trim do you want?

Comment: I've just copied your code into a new solution (with a little clean up of things we don't need). I cannot reproduce your issue, the command method gets invoked on clicking the button. Perhaps there is something wrong in your full setup...

Comment: @dymanoid Can I see your code please so I can compare that one to what I have please? When you say "full setup" what should I take a look at? Also what are the "things that we don't need" ?

Comment: Please see [here](http://pastebin.com/gYpwNU5W). The things I removed are, e.g., the database loading code which doesn't affect the functionality being tested (invoking of an `ICommand.Execute()` method).

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't make it work. Any suggestions please?